# Floating HTML list items with different height

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I want to float my list items into a grid like structure depending on the available width.

Unfortunately my items are of different hight and sometimes the  items don't wrap all the way to the left. In the example I made the first item a little higher to show the problem, in reality I have no idea which item will be which height.

How can I make the 2nd row start a little further down, but always on the left side ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
li {display: block; width:200px; height:100px; float:left; border:1px solid;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li style="height:110px;"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please create a Jsfiddle for the same so that we may be able to look into your problem http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) instead of `float: left/right`

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/PUQNg/1/)

Further reading: [What’s the Deal With Display: Inline-Block?](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)

Answer (score 2):

To make inline use "`display:inline:block` property" this should resolve both your issue:- 
1) coming in line
2) It gives spacing too between elements

But if you think all objects might have different height, I would recommend use "`vertical-align:top`" and along with that "`margin-bottom:5px`" to give space, as `vertical-align:top`removes the space too between rows.

here is the code:-

**HTML:**

```
    <ul>
<li style="height:110px;"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
   display: inline-block; 
   width:200px; 
   height:100px; 
   border:1px solid; 
   vertical-align:top; 
   margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

You can refer to the Fiddle here:- **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/2Uygc/**

Please let me know if this resolves you issue.

Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome, thanks, just what I was looking for. Because I wanted everything to be align to the top. Which it dose with Float and not Inline-block.